# I need to create a Dynamic gallery in Wordpress using a custom field and the DIVI Template Builder

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to create a custom template for a holidays houses rental website, using Wordpress and DIVI THEME.

The problem is that I found that, in order to create a different Image Gallery for every flat, I must use a Custom Field for Gallery.

I found Advanced Custom Fields plugin, but after I create the GALLERY Field, I don't know how to integrate it inside the DIVI THEME BUILDER, in order to create 1 gallery for each flat in the articles.

My goal is to create a Global BODY TEMPLATE for all the flats (using the Divi Template Builder with Dynamic Contents) where we can insert from the backend the custom fields like: Beds, Rooms, People, Conforts, etc. and of course the Image Gallery and than they will appear on the front end using the graphic and template that I already created in the Theme Builder of Divi.

I know is a weird question... But is there anybody who can help me? Thank you <3

Comment: Hello: I am also looking to do exactly the same thing. I would like that the persons creating the posts for their property to be able to upload 10 (or whatever number of images that I specify) and that those images would be used within the Divi Gallery Dynamically. I was able to create everything else from price to renter using other Divi Dynamic fiends. Have you ever figured a way around this as to not have to do it manually?

Comment: Hello I found a solution for this. There is a plugin here very helpful and low budget to fix this: https://diviengine.com/product/divi-machine/

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for same solution and find out you can use" [gallery] " as short code in your divi code module
but there is limitations for customizations
else you can use https://www.elegantthemes.com/marketplace/divi-gallery-extended/